# Piano - How to edit/remove mistakes of a piece I played

Tags: piano, audio-editing

I have recorded a piece (GoPro and a stereo condensor microphone) and there I played a wrong note which destroyed my entire piece...so I want to ask whether there are programs do edit this mistake.
The grand piano got some mistuned notes, am I able to fix them either?
I hear of people soing this very often but I only found Piano Roll / Logic X which are probably not for non-digital piano.

Comment: As a professional producer, I'd suggest getting your piano tuned and rerecording the piece. Any edits made to such a recording run the risk of sounding synthetic and, honestly, bad. Do it right first and the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you recorded it as audio rather than Midi, then the only tool I'm aware of that can change the pitch of any single note is [Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne) (& editing one note in a chord is only possible in the highest editions*, the basic can't do that) so you're looking at minimum €399 for that functionality.

Alternatively, play the incorrect part again & edit it into the existing version - best done right as you made the mistake... pause, do that bit again & continue to the end. That way you have a consistent feel & a simple linear editing task in any DAW.

*needs a version with DNA Direct Note Access™ for polyphonic audio